# Alter table to modify default value of column

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table

I have a requirement where we need to modify a column's default value in database table. The table is already an existing table in database and currently the default value of the column is NULL.
Now if add a new default value to this column, If I am correct it updates all the existing NULLs of the column to new DEfault value. Is there a way to not to do this but still set a new default value on column.
I mean I do not want the existing NULLs to be updated and want them to remain as NULLs.

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is the datatype of your column ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Your belief about what will happen is not correct.  Setting a default value for a column will not affect the existing data in the table.

I create a table with a column `col2` that has no default value

```
SQL> create table foo(
  2    col1 number primary key,
  3    col2 varchar2(10)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo( col1 ) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo( col1 ) values (2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo( col1 ) values (3);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3
```

If I then alter the table to set a default value, nothing about the existing rows will change

```
SQL> alter table foo
  2    modify( col2 varchar2(10) default 'foo' );

Table altered.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3

SQL> insert into foo( col1 ) values (4);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3
         4 foo
```

Even if I subsequently change the default again, there will still be no change to the existing rows

```
SQL> alter table foo
  2    modify( col2 varchar2(10) default 'bar' );

Table altered.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3
         4 foo

SQL> insert into foo( col1 ) values (5);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1 COL2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3
         4 foo
         5 bar
```

Comment: Good example.  As a trivial shortcut, the datatype isn't needed when only adding a default.  You can just do `alter table foo modify (col2 default 'bar')`

Comment: @rimsky Neat shortcut but https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-redefine-column appears to suggest otherwise. Perhaps the documentation is misleading. It also mentions `ALTER [COLUMN] col_name {SET DEFAULT literal | DROP DEFAULT}`.

Comment: @trss you are quoting from MySQL documentation, but the question is tagged `oracle`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't notice those tiny tags. Will be helpful if the question mentions Oracle too.

Answer (score 10):

```sql
ALTER TABLE *table_name*
MODIFY *column_name* DEFAULT *value*;
```

worked in Oracle

e.g:

```sql
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
MODIFY MY_COLUMN DEFAULT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLE NAME}
ALTER COLUMN {COLUMN NAME} SET DEFAULT '{DEFAULT VALUES}'
```

example :

```
ALTER TABLE RESULT
ALTER COLUMN STATUS SET DEFAULT 'FAIL'
```

Comment: For some reason this raises ORA-01735 error: Alter Table MGRA.TAB1 ALTER COLUMN ID_PRO SET DEFAULT 1;

Comment: I think this is T-SQL (MS SQL), not Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Following Justin's example, the command below works in Postgres:

`alter table foo alter column col2 set default 'bar';`

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> MODIFY <column_name> DEFAULT <defult_value>

EX: ALTER TABLE AAA MODIFY ID DEFAULT AAA_SEQUENCE.nextval
```

Tested on Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score -2):

For Sql Azure the following query works :

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD  DEFAULT 'DefaultValue' FOR ColumnName
GO
```