# Altering table property to default when NULL only for new inserts

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way in Oracle that we can set Default column value when NULL only for New inserts? I don't want to change the Existing records if they have NULL.

I want to do this at table level. Not with NVL insert logic.

Comment: Your question is actually very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057275/alter-table-to-modify-default-value-of-column), but I gave an answer below as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, if you alter the table and set a default value for a column, it should only affect *new* records which would come in via an insert, not existing records.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable MODIFY (col VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT 'some value');
```

Using the above approach, `col` values which are *already* `NULL` should remain `NULL`, at least from the point of view of inserts not changing those `NULL` values.  And newly inserted records which do not specify a value for `col` should receive the default value `some value`.

Comment: I tried this. The old values didn't change. But when I insert new records with NULL. It gets inserted as NULL. It doesn't get the default value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration which shows what's going on.

First, a test table and some inserts:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, col varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (id, col) values (1, null);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, col) values (2, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID COL
---------- ----------
         1
         2 Littlefoot
```

Alter the table so that newly added rows contain 'some value' for the COL column:

```
SQL> alter table test modify col default 'some value';

Table altered.
```

OK; and now, important part of the story: pay attention to following:

```
SQL> -- this won't work as you wanted, because I explicitly inserted NULL into COL
SQL> insert into test (id, col) values (3, null);

1 row created.

SQL> -- this will work, because COL is omitted from the INSERT statement
SQL> insert into test (id) values (4);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- ----------
         1
         2 Littlefoot
         3
         4 some value

SQL>
```

See? If you explicitly put NULL into a column, it won't get the default value.

---

**However**, if you were on 12c (I know, you aren't - just saying, for future reference), there's yet another option: `DEFAULT ON NULL`. It goes like this:

```
SQL> alter table test modify col default on null 'some value';
alter table test modify col default on null 'some value'
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02296: cannot enable (SCOTT.) - null values found
```

Ooops! Won't work if there are NULLs in the column. I know #2 that you don't want to modify existing rows, but - for this demonstration, I'll do that:

```
SQL> update test set col = 'x' where col is null;

2 rows updated.

SQL> alter table test modify col default on null 'some value';

Table altered.
```

OK; let's see how it behaves: I'm explicitly inserting NULL into the column. In the previous example, it didn't put 'some value' in there, but left it NULL. How about now?

```
SQL> insert into test (id, col) values (5, null);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

        ID COL
---------- ----------
         1 x
         2 Littlefoot
         3 x
         4 some value
         5 some value
```

Nice; we have 'some value' in the column.

---

Now you have some more info about the issue; see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As Littlefoot mentioned, *If you explicitly put `NULL` into a column, it won't get the default value*.

If no value is mentioned for the column in the insert query, it uses `DEFAULT`. But, an explicit `NULL` overrides the default expression.

For 12c and above you can use the  `DEFAULT ON NULL` option.
For prior versions, only way as far as I can tell is to replicate that functionality  through a `TRIGGER`

```
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE (  yourcolumn VARCHAR(100) );


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_mod_yourtabcol BEFORE
     INSERT ON yourtable
     FOR EACH ROW
     WHEN ( new.yourcolumn IS NULL )

BEGIN
     :new.yourcolumn := 'SOME DEFAULT VALUE';
END;
/


INSERT INTO YOURTABLE(yourcolumn) VALUES(NULL);

select * from YOURTABLE;
```

---

```
Table YOURTABLE created.


Trigger TRG_MOD_YOURTABCOL compiled


1 row inserted.


YOURCOLUMN                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOME DEFAULT VALUE

1 row selected.
```