# Insert statement with blank values without defining all columns

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I have a need to insert 100+ rows of data into a table that has 25 text columns.
I only want to insert some data into those columns and the rest be represented by a white space.

(Note: Text fields on PeopleSoft tables are defined as NOT NULLABLE, with a single white space character used to indicate no data instead of null.)

Is there a way to write an insert statement that does not define all the columns along with the blank space.  As an example:

```
INSERT INTO CUST.RECORD(BUSINESS_UNIT, PROJECT_ID, EFF_STATUS, TMPL, DESCR) VALUES('TOO1','PROJ1','A','USA00','USA00 CONTRACT');
```

For every other column in CUST.RECORD I'd like to insert ' ' without defining the column or the space in the insert.

Comment: If you're just trying to save some typing for a single SQL statement then you're probably out of luck. But if this is a pattern you want to repeat for many inserts, or many tables, there are options that can help. But any solution would require creating PL/SQL objects, and would also depend on the database version. (For example, there might be a way to use polymorphic table functions, but that requires at least version 18c.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set a Default value in table definition like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST.RECORD(
  id          NUMBER DEFAULT detail_seq.NEXTVAL,
  master_id   varchar2(10) DEFAULT ' ',
  description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

**Edit**: for your table you can use :

```
alter table  CUST.RECORD modify( col2 varchar2(10) default ' ' );
```

Comment: That would work but the table exists and can't be dropped/recreated without far more work than just writing out the insert by hand.  I will keep that in my back pocket for future use!

Comment: You can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21057275/alter-table-to-modify-default-value-of-column

Comment: "One way is to set a Default value in table definition"  Incorrect.  As long as a column is nullable -- defined _without_ the 'not null' clause, it very will _can_  be inserted with no data at all.

Comment: @EdStevens look at this https://blog.pythian.com/adding-columns-with-default-values-and-not-null-in-oracle-11g/

Comment: @FarshidShekari - so what's your point?  The article shows how oracle improved its internal handling about _adding_ a 'not null with default' column to a table.  The OP is asking about not having to specify data for every column.   That said, on second reading I do see where you wrote "One way is to set a Default" and somehow I read the "one" as "only" -- "only way is to ..."  My apologies.

Comment: In Oracle `''` (zero-length string) is the same as `NULL` so `DEFAULT ''` is the same as `DEFAULT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to supply a value for a specific column *IF* either condition is true:

1. The column is defined as nullable. That is, it was NOT defined with the 'not null' clause.

or

2. The column is defined with a default value

   SQL> create table my_test (my_id number not null,
   2                        fname varchar2(10),        -- nullable
   3                        dob date default sysdate   -- default value
   4                       )
   5  ;

   Table created.

   SQL> --
   SQL> -- only supplying value for my_id
   SQL> insert into my_test(my_id) values (1);

   1 row created.

   SQL> --
   SQL> -- and see the results
   SQL> select *
   2  from my_test;

   ```
     MY_ID FNAME      DOB
   ```

   ---

   ```
         1            12-MAR-21
   ```

   1 row selected.

   SQL> --
   SQL> select my_id,
   2         nvl(fname,'NULL'),
   3         dob
   4  from my_test;

   ```
     MY_ID NVL(FNAME, DOB
   ```

   ---

   ```
         1 NULL       12-MAR-21
   ```

   1 row selected.